# Removing White Space

Tags: vba, excel, whitespace

I need help creating separate text files from each row in an excel spread sheet called "worksheet". I want the text files to be named with content of Column A + “Result”+ Column H (Which should be hidden in the .txt file, with columns B-G being the content, I have done the coding. Please find the followings. But I have received whitespace in the .txt output file. Please find the screenshots. I am unable to TRIM this white space.

How would I proceed further to solve the problem?

Thanks in Advance.

VBA Code:

```
Sub WriteTotxt()

Const forReading = 1, forAppending = 3, fsoForWriting = 2
Dim fs, objTextStream, sText As String
Dim lLastRow As Long, lRowLoop As Long, lLastCol As Long, lColLoop As Long

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For lRowLoop = 1 To lLastRow

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextStream = fs.opentextfile("D:\EXCEL_TXT_TEST\New folder\" & Cells(lRowLoop, 8) & "-" & "RESULT" & "-" & Cells(lRowLoop, 1) & ".txt", fsoForWriting, True)

    sText = ""
    sText1 = ""

    For lColLoop = 1 To 7
    If lColLoop <> 7 Then

        sText = sText & "<" & Cells(lColLoop) & ">" & "," & Chr(0)
        sText1 = sText1 & Cells(lRowLoop, lColLoop) & "," & Chr(0)

     Else

      sText = sText & "<" & Cells(lColLoop) & ">" & Chr(0)
      sText1 = sText1 & Cells(lRowLoop, lColLoop) & Chr(0)

      End If


    Next lColLoop

    objTextStream.writeline (Left(sText, Len(Trim(sText)) - 1))
    objTextStream.writeline (Left(sText1, Len(Trim(sText1)) - 1))


    objTextStream.Close
    Set objTextStream = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing

Next lRowLoop

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I think TRIM only works on CHR(32) not CHR(0).

Comment: But if we use CHR(32) instead of CHR (0) then last character of the file content will be removed. any suggestion ?

Comment: because of these two lines? 
    `objTextStream.writeline (Left(sText, Len(Trim(sText)) - 1))
    objTextStream.writeline (Left(sText1, Len(Trim(sText1)) - 1))`. you are doing left( , Len() - 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the blank lines from a string like this
`mystr = replace(mystr, vblf & vbcr, "")`
This will remove empty lines, not lines that contain spaces or other characters you can't see though..

Answer (score 0):

I can help with your code as well, but have you tried a simple approach first?

Why don't you just **file --> save as .csv**, and replace your header? Your data output will be VERY similar, save for the `" "` space preceding your listed entries. Lazy but easy.

adapt this to your module, and you can erase like everything you have ...

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"c:\MyFile.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
, CreateBackup:=False
```

Then, just read your data back in, and string operations will be easy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be grate if you can help me in my code , as there is some specific requirement for this. Thanks again.